# Is it possible to fail a maven build if fortify scan reports errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, fortify

I have a Maven project. I have run the Fortify scan for this and generated the pdf report successfully. I am now trying to integrate this, as part of the Maven build, and assume adding the appropriate jars as dependancies should do the job.

My question is,

1. Is it possible to cause the build to fail, even if all code is fine,
   but the Fortify reports generate an error?
2. If yes, how do I specify that I want the build to fail only on say,
   High and Critical errors, and not Low and Medium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Maven Enforcer](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/index.html) to enforce that build should fail when report is not generated , or you could use some other [Enforcer rules](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/).

For example some thing like this, You can set the `phase` and `Rules` when you want to fail.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-fortify-reports</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce-once</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
           <requireFilesExist>
                  <files>
                   <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}/report.frp</file>
                  </files>
                </requireFilesExist>
          </rules>
          <fail>true</fail>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Not a full solution but a hint)*

You can use the FPRUtility (part of SCA) to check errors and number of issues, then you can use Maven or Ant to parse the result and fail the build.

```
# fprutility -information -project project.fpr -errors
[10002] Unable to parse T-SQL at tables.sql:612:3.
[10002] Unable to parse T-SQL at update.sql:72:27.

# fprutility -information -project project.fpr -search -query "[fortify priority order]:high OR [fortify priority order]:critical"
565 issues of 796 matched search query.
```

**EDIT:**

*Note: if you use SSC to audit issues you should upload the generated .fpr file first then check the merged results to exclude suppressed issues for example.*